# How to solve for matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, least-squares

How can I solve [image: eq1], where [image: eq2] and [image: eq3] and [image: eq4] [image: eq5] in the **least squares sense** in matlab?

So I'd like to have the minimizing [image: eq6] as output.

Comment: Is the matrix norm used in `||Ca-b||^2` the 2-norm?

Comment: @Jubobs: I think this does not matter, since we are finite dimensional and thus every norm is equivalent to each other. So we are free to choose any norm we want. 2-norm is fine, but e.g. the Frobenius norm should work as well.

Comment: Well, if you differentiate the square of the Frobenius norm of `C a - b` wrt to `C` (use the [matrix cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)), you find the `C` matrix that minimises that quantity in the least-square sense can be computed in MATLAB with `b * a' / (a * a')`.

Comment: @Jubobs: isn't the derivative (Matlab notation) 2*(Ca-b)*a', which has to be equal to 0. Then if I solve for C: Caa'-ba'=0 <=> Caa'=ba' <=> aa'C'=ab' <=> C'=aa'\ab' <=> C=(a*a'\a*b')', the other way around of what you computed?
And why is this the solution in the least-square sense?

Comment: Norms being equivalent does not mean that minimisation problems with different norms have the same solution. For example if A is a nx1 matrix of ones then the minimiser of ||A*x-b|| is the mean of the b's if the norm is the l2 norm, while one of the many minimisers for the l1 norm is the median.

Comment: @dmuir: Ok, thx. Nevertheless Frobenius norm works out for me :)

Comment: @ Jubobs: Already did....ages ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the quantity to minimise as

`||Xa - b||^2`

`=` (definition of the Frobenius norm)

`Tr{(Xa - b) (Xa - b)'}`

`=` (expand matrix-product expression)

`Tr{Xaa'X' - ba'X' - Xab' + bb'}`

`=` (linearity of the trace operator)

`Tr{Xaa'X'} - Tr{ba'X'} - Tr{Xab'} + Tr{bb'}`

`=` (trace of transpose of a matrix = trace of the matrix)

`Tr{Xaa'X'} - 2 Tr{ba'X'} + Tr{bb'}`

where `'` denotes the transpose operator (because all matrices involved are real, transpose and conjugate transpose are the same).
Now, if you refer to section 2.5 of the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), you'll find that

- the derivative of `Tr{Xaa'X'}` is `2Xaa'` (see equation 111),
- the derivative of `Tr{ba'X'}` is `ba'` (see equation 104),
- the derivative of `Tr{bb'}` is `0` (because this expression doesn't depend on `X`).

(Differentiation is performed with respect to matrix `X`).

Therefore, the matrix that minimises the quantity of interest satisfies

```
2Xaa' = 2ba'
Xaa' = ba'
```

Therefore, you can use MATLAB's matrix right-division operator, `/`, to compute `X`:

```
X = b * a' / (a * a');
```

Comment: Yes, I think your answer and mine (above in the comments) is actually the same...

Comment: @SemtexB Our solutions should only be the same if `b * a'` and `a * a'` commute.

Comment: I first transposed and used the mldivide, whereas you did not transpose and used mrdivide, thus it should be the same, shouldn't it?

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html
http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mrdivide.html

Comment: @SemtexB Ah yes. I hadn't seen the last `'` in `C=(aa'\ab')'` in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849550/how-to-solve-for-matrix-in-matlab/30855643?noredirect=1#comment49745965_30849550).

Comment: @Jubobs - Bonjour!  I've made a chat room for us to talk about anything related to MATLAB that may be off-topic, or can't fit in the span of a comment.  Visit us when you have the time!  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the invitation `:)` I'm busy at the moment, but I'll pop in for a chat later.

Comment: @Jubobs - Of course! Visit when you have the time :) No rush at all.